# If I switch to the Steam version of a game, do my saves survive?

Tags: steam, braid

I purchased the humble indie bundle 2, downloaded braid, and installed it. Since the bundle is now available on Steam, I am now downloading the Steam version for achievements etc. Will the steam version use the same save as the non-Steam version?

Related: If I have the non-Steam version of a game and the Steam version, is it possible to make Steam only redownload changed files? Not a huge issue for the Humble Indie games, being quite small in size, but it would be handy for something like UT3 if I activated my key on Steam.

Comment: Despite my self answer, there is still room for someone else to answer if this is true for all Steam games, however.

Comment: I imagine it would vary by game.

Comment: Yes, it varies by game.  If they store the saves in a single, common location in all versions then it won't matter.  If it stores it in the game's directory (BAD DEVELOPER, no cookie!) or in the Steam cloud, then no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have now redownloaded Braid, and was not only given my old save file, but achievements based on my existing progress.